# How to fix a deleted USB flash drive partition?

Tags: mac, usb, bootable-media

I was trying to make a Kali Linux bootable. By mistake I deleted the complete USB flash drive partition and now its all free space.

Ubuntu and Mac both are not accepting the USB flash drive and I also don’t get any options to create a new partition or something like that.

I used the build in disk utility on Mac and disks on Ubuntu. For bootable I am planning to use `dd`.

Initially usb had NTFS file system. I transferred all its data to other folder.  I formatted it to have macOS extended. Then I tried making it bootable using `dd` but it was taking too long so I assumed something is wrong and terminated the process. Then I opened the same usb in ubuntu(in a virtual box) and in disks I removed the complete partition of the USB flash drive.

Comment: Please click [edit] and advise the formatting used originally by the USB Flash Drive; FAT32 or something else? Please do not click Add Comment as old comments can get pushed off screen by new comments; you're the one with the flash drive in their hand and your findings are essential to a solution, therefore should go in the Question.

Comment: What have you done to create a new partition on the drive?